# Arrow navigation up/down/right/left with JS and background position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm looking for this exactly navigation on my website:
http://fetedelabiere.promo-agency.com/

I need a background-position navigation trought the user click,
Right arrow moves the background to 25% or 50% position to the right, and the same when it clicks on the up or down arrow. 
Im' new at the js and can't figure it out how to make the same effect and the website I mentioned.

Here is my code so far, but I cant apply the up and down arrow navigation.

```
<div class="large-12 columns altura-largura">

    <button class="button" id="btn-direita"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>
    <button class="button" id="btn-esquerda"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></button>
    <div class="page page-id-240" id="simpleBG" style="background-position: 0% 0px;"></div>

</div>
```

And the JS:

```
var currentPos = $('#simpleBG').css('background-position');
var elementPositions = currentPos.split(' ');

var x = Number(elementPositions[0].replace(/[^0-9-]/g, ''));
x = (x == 100) ? 0 : x += 50;



$('#btn-direita').click(function(){

$('#simpleBG').css('background-position', function (i, value) {
      var x = parseInt(value, 10);
      return (x == 100 ? 0 : x + 50) + "%" + " 0";
  });

});




var currentPos2 = $('#simpleBG').css('background-position');
var elementPositions2 = currentPos2.split(' ');

var y = Number(elementPositions2[0].replace(/[^0-9-]/g, ''));
y = (y == 100) ? 0 : y -= 50;


$('#btn-esquerda').click(function(){


    $('#simpleBG').css('background-position', function (i, value) {
          var y = parseInt(value, 10);
          return (y == 100 ? 0 : y - 50) + "%" + " 0";
      });

});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Please clarify if possible

Comment: Edited, I hope I could made it more clear now, basically I need improve this navigation on my website and I have no idea how: [link](http://fetedelabiere.promo-agency.com/)

Comment: That `"50% 0px" < "100% 0px"` is not true with javascript, your need int values to make a proper check

Comment: Edit the if but still can't figute it out how to make the up/down navigation with this system, if the user clicks on up or down it need to save his click if he clicks to the right first, this code should be like click to the right and go += 50% I guess